# Why id returns as undefined in the console when using this.props.match.params?.id?

Tags: reactjs, parameters, crud

I tried to display data relevant to a specific post when click on it. But this.props.match.params?.id not return the id. I used the URL by manually typing the id like '/expense/61362fcbe355c7474eaa45c7'. Then it worked fine. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      expense: {},
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const id = this.props.match?.params.id;

    axios.get(`/expense/${id}`).then((res) => {
      if (res.data.success) {
        this.setState({
          expense: res.data.expense,
          init: 1,
        });

        console.log(this.state.expense);
      }
    });
  }
```

Dynamic Route

```
import ExpenseDetails from './ExpenseDetails';

<Route path="/expense/:id">
     <ExpenseDetails />
</Route>
```

Comment: You will need to set up a dynamic route to accept that param first. Some thing like: `/expense/:id`

Comment: You need to pass id in the Link to the route in order to extract it from params

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a link dynamic or push route using the `history` props.

```
 const id = 'any';
 history.push(`/expense/${id}`)
```

After that, you can access it in your component `this.props.match?.params?.id`.

You can use `const { id } = useParams();` hooks for getting id in your
functonal component.

```
<Route path="/:id/details">
 <Details />
</Route>

<Link to="/2/details">Details</Link>

function Details() {
 const { id } = useParams();

 return (
  <div>
   <h2>Now showing post {id}</h2>
  </div>
 );
}
```